# Storeing 2 values in a rowcolumn (mysql) eg Cards in a Collection of cards

Tags: php, mysql, database-design, pdo

I'm trying to set up a database for a website where it's possible to make collections using mysql (I'm retrieving the db entries with PHP and PDO
I'm having trouble creating the right database setup in mysql. Let me explain my situation:

I have Users, Collections and Cards.
A user can create collections. The collections are assigned to the user.
The user can add cards from the cards table to his collection. I also wan't the user to add an extra value to the cards in his collection eg. shipped, tobuy or bought.

The setup I have now is as follows (simplified):

**User table:** userid, username, password
01 | Jack | jackspass
02 | John | johnspass
03 | Peter | peterspass

**Collection table:** collectionid, collectionname, userid
01 | JackFirstCollection | 01
02 | JohnCardCollection | 02
03 | JacksSecondCollection | 01

**Cards table:** cardid, cardname, cardattr 
01 | CardOne |  yellow
02 | CardTwo | blue
03 | CardThree | red

My first question is how can I create new collections and link a user and cards to it?
*This has been answered by @Piotrm where he suggested using a junction table. I will look into this before marking as solved.*
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UvMZqwyErrs Used this to make a Junction Table.

My second question concerns the cards that are going to be linked to the collections. I want to assign an extra value to each card in the collections.
For example CardOne is in Jack's JackFirstCollection. I want to assign Shipped, ToBuy or InCollection value to that card inside the collection.
How would one create that inside mysql, or with the suggested junction table?

Thanks so much in advance!

Comment: define the relation between each tables, like `user` HAS_MANY `collection`, `collection` HAS_MANY `card`, and `user` HAS_MANY `card` via `collection`, something like that. Then you should be able to decide the db architecture automatically. Currently, I am not able to get the relation. And yes, it has nothing to with php or mysql.

Comment: Could you please clarify that where you are facing problem.(In database creation, php connection with database, query handling or report generation)?

Comment: You probably need a junction table between collection and cards as you can have many cards in a collection and many collections can have the same card. You can also put extra info in this junction table.

Comment: Thanks for commenting. I updated my post in order to clarify my questions, hope its more clear this way.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The answer piotrm gave me was the sollution to my problem.

I made a junction table using the above youtube video.